# Cauchy integration with factorials

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I have a question;

> Let $\gamma$ be the circular contour, positively oriented, with centre $0$ and radius $8$. Compute the following integral
> $$\int \frac{5!\cos(z)}{(z-2\pi )^6}$$

I used the formula $$f^n(a)= \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n+1}}$$

So I wrote $$f^n(a)=\frac{5!}{2\pi i} \int \frac{\cos  z}{(z-2\pi)^6}$$

= $$\frac{5!}{2 \pi i} . \frac{2 \pi i}{5!}.f^5(2 \pi)=1$$

I'm new to Cauchy integrals so I'm not sure if I did this right help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Is $f^{(5)}(2\pi)=1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526074/cauchy-integral-formula-for-oint-gamma-i-fracz21zz-8dz-gamma-i?rq=1

Comment: I wrote f(z) as cosz and I f^5 (cos(z))=cosz so it would be cos 2pi if im not mistaken?

Comment: @SarahAngel No it is $-\sin z $.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem concerning the notation: it's $f^{(n)}$, not $f^n$. Besides, when you write:$$f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{5!}{2\pi i}\int\frac{\cos z}{(z-2\pi)^6},$$

- $\mathrm dz$ is missing;
- $\gamma$ is missing;
- you don't tell us what $a$ is.

But the idea is correct.

Comment: and the parenthesis in the exponent means that many number of times differentiated, or am i tired?

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, that's what it means.

Comment: I just wanted to clarify it as no one else had pointed it out.

Comment: That was all the information given to me in the question